# Roots of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.

Tags: analysis, roots, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

It is known that the roots of the [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html), denote it by $U_n(x)$, are in the interval $(-1,1)$ and they are simple (of multiplicity one). I have noticed that the roots of $U_n{(x)}+U_{n-1}(x)$ (by looking at the law ranks of $n$) also lies in $(-1,1)$, I also noticed that  for $(1-x)U_n{(x)}+U_{n-1}(x)$ the roots lie in  $(-2,2)$. But I don't have any idea how to prove that in general, I wonder, first, if these claims are true? and how can I start proving them?

Comment: For the second case, it seems that you can cut down the interval to (-1, $\sqrt{2}$)

Comment: @ekkilop I just wanted to be safe that is why I rounded to these numbers, otherwise you are right low rank calculations confirm what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227311/roots-of-the-chebyshev-polynomials-of-the-second-kind/227412#227412) by writing chebyshev polynomial explicitly in terms of $x = \cos t$. 
Update: I also show there that the roots are all real.

Answer (score 6):

For your first case:

Since
$U_n(x)
=\frac{\sin((n+1)t)}{\sin(t)}
$
where
$x = \cos(t)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
U_n(x)+U_{n-1}(x)
&=\frac{\sin((n+1)t)}{\sin(t)}+\frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}\\
&=\frac{\sin((n+1)t)+\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}\\
&=\frac{2\sin((n+1/2)t)\cos(t/2)}{\sin(t)}\\
\end{array}
$

and this is zero when
$t(n+1/2)
=k\pi
$
for some integer $k$,
or
$t
=\frac{k\pi}{n+1/2}
$
for
$1 \le k \le n$.

This gives $n$ real roots,
and that is all
since
$U_n(x)+U_{n-1}(x)$
is of degree $n$.

Comment: I am working on your second case.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort

Comment: The second case is not simplifying like the first. Frustrating.

Comment: do you recommend asking it in Mathoverflow?

Comment: Sure can't hurt.

Comment: @Math137 I'd bet they won't accept your question at MO. It's for professional mathematicians...

Comment: @draks... do you expect an easy answer for the second part? Which is basically the purpose of the question.

Comment: Note, $\cos(t/2)$ is not zero when $t=\pi/2$. Did you mean $t/2=\pi/2$?

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I will change it. Upvoted.

Comment: $t=\pi$ is not a root ($U_n(-1)+U_{n-1}(-1)=(-1)^n$).  All $n$ roots are $t=\frac{k\pi}{n+\frac12}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will update my answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

For your second case:

Since
$U_n(x)
=\frac{\sin((n+1)t)}{\sin(t)}
$
where
$x = \cos(t)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(x-1)U_n(x)+U_{n-1}(x)
&=(\cos(t)-1)\frac{\sin((n+1)t)}{\sin(t)}+\frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}\\
&=\frac{(\cos(t)-1)\sin((n+1)t)+\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}\\
\end{array}
$

Putting this into Wolfy,
this has this many roots
from $0$ to $\pi$
for these values of $n$:

$2: 1;
3: 2; 
4: 3;
5:4
 $

This seems to show that
this has $n-1$ real roots.
Since this is a
polynomial of degree $n+1$,
there should be
one complex pair of roots.
This is confirmed by Wolfy
directly by entering
"$(x-1)ChebyshevU[n, x]+ChebyshevU[n-1, x]=0
$"
for various values of $n$.

In all the cases I have tries,
all $n-1$ real roots
are between
$-1$ and $1$.

Other than this,
I haven't been able
to make any real progress
proving the result.